# Geometric interpretation of ranks of matrices gathering coefficients of 3 affine and associated vectorial planes

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, analytic-geometry, affine-geometry

Given three planes $\pi_{1}, \pi_{2},\pi_{3}$ $\subseteq \mathbb{R}^{3}$ with their respect cartesian equation of the form $A_{i}x + B_{i}y + C_{i}z + D_{i} = 0$, we can determine their relative position in space by comparing the rank of the coefficient matrix $M$, with the rank of the augmented matrix $M^{*}$, where $$M = \begin{pmatrix}
A_{1}& B_{1} & C_{1} \\ 
 A_{2} & B_{2} & C_{2} \\ 
 A_{3}&  B_{3}& C_{3}
\end{pmatrix}$$ and $$ M^{*} = \begin{pmatrix}
A_{1}& B_{1} & C_{1} & D_{1}\\ 
 A_{2} & B_{2} & C_{2} & D_{2} \\ 
 A_{3}&  B_{3}& C_{3} & D_{3}
\end{pmatrix}$$ What is the geometric interpretation of these two matrices, how do they affect the planes relatively to each other visually?

My guess has been that $rank(M)$ expresses if some of the planes have the same direction, while $rank(M^{*})$ also checks if they are separated by a distance or not. However, I have been struggling to understand why 3 separated parallel planes have $rank(M) = 1$ but $rank(M^{*}) = 2$, according to my textbook.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange! How exactly do you define $M$? What is the augmented matrix $M^*$? Also, I guess you mean $\pi_i \subseteq \mathbb{R}^3$.

Comment: @PantelisSopasakis Thanks for your reply! I've edited the post with the definition of the matrices. Sorry if I may misuse some of the mathematical symbols, I don't know a lot about math (looking forward to improve though!), so I was simply referring that the planes are in space.

Comment: I have taken the liberty to modify your title in order for it to stick to the content of your question, and, as well, to attract further users.

Comment: @JeanMarie Thank you very much!

Comment: I have the same question as you, @Arnau. Moreover, having three parallel (and not overlapping) planes I would expect $rank(M^{*}) = 3$. I'm wondering why it is 2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This array displays the different possible cases :

[image]

Let us first recall that the rank of a matrix $M$ can be considered at least from 2 angles of attack: (a) rank of its columns' space or (b) max. size of a non zero determinant of a submatrix.

Remark; there is a third characterization: (c) by using rank-nullity theorem: $rank=4-dim(ker(M))$.

Now, let us explain some aspects of the array above.

4 squares are hatched due to the fact that

$$rank(M^*) = \begin{cases} rank(M)\\ or \ \ rank(M)+1\end{cases}$$

Indeed,the rank of $M$ is (characterization (a) above) the dimension of $E:=vect (columns(M))$; extending $M$ to $M^*$ amounts to add a column belonging already to $E$ (rank preserved) or not (rank increased by one unit).

I do not give a detail for each case. Let me only give a treatment of the case you have been struggling with, the case of 3 parallel planes.

Their equations

$$ax+by+cz=d_k \ \ k=1,2,3$$

involve matrix :

$$\begin{pmatrix}
a&b&c&d_1\\ 
a&b&c&d_2\\  
a&b&c&d_3\\ 
\end{pmatrix}$$

on which we could discuss its rank (rank = 1 or rank = 2) using characterization (b). But it is simpler to consider it from the point of view of linear combinations:

$$\exists x,y,z \ s.t. \ x \begin{pmatrix}
a\\ 
a \\ 
a
\end{pmatrix}+y\begin{pmatrix}
b\\ 
b \\ 
b
\end{pmatrix}+z\begin{pmatrix}
c\\ 
c \\ 
c
\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}
d_{1}\\ 
d_{2} \\ 
d_{3}
\end{pmatrix}\tag{2}$$

which will have a solution (in fact an infinite number of solutions) if and only if the last vector is in the range space of the first three ones, i.e., if and only if **all** its entries are identical. If one of the entries is different from the others, the rank of $M^*$ becomes $2$.

Let us come back a short while on the case where $d_1=d_2=d_3$. In this case, (2) is equivalent to the fact that $x+y+z-d_1=0$ has a 2 dimensional space of solutions.

Comment: I have the same owner's question and I understood your explanation. But why couldn't $rank(M^{*}) = 3$? My guess is that this way the three planes would be separated by some distance. When I see $rank(M^{*}) = 2$, I imagine two overlapping planes and another one parallel to them, not three parallel (and not overlapping) planes...

Comment: 1) First question: because you cannot have rank(M)=1 and rank(M*)=3 (adding a column can at most modify the rank by $1$). Have I well understood your question ? 2) Second question : In the box in the middle of the top row, I write "3 parallel planes not **all** identical", this case is considered (two identical planes + another one parallel to them but not the same).

Comment: Oh, I just realized this point: "adding a column can at most modify the rank by 1", thanks. Just curious: does any math demonstration exist for that? And just to confirm: in order to have 3 parallel and not overlapping planes I don't need $rank(M^{*}) = 3$, right? How truthful is then this OP's statement?: "$rank(M^{*})$  also checks if they are separated by a distance or not".

Comment: @chick3n0x07CC Your comment has triggered a re-writing of my answer which was definitely not clear. Does it answers your last questions ? I didn't discuss the "separated by a distance or not" because for me it means "non all identical" or "identical" (with the intermediate case  say $d_1=d_2\ne d_3$ or all identical.

Comment: I think I have it. If column $\begin{pmatrix}d_{1} & d_{2} &  d_{3}\end{pmatrix}$ is linear combination of the others (which means the three equations of the planes are proportional), $rank(M^{*}) = 1$ and all planes will be overlapping. If it is not linear combination, then $rank(M^{*}) = 2$ and whichever two planes will be overlapping while the remaining one will not (the "non **all** identical" case you mentioned).

Comment: Would the characterization "(a) rank of its columns' space" be the same as "rank of its row's space"? Since having a matrix $A$ implies that $rank(A) = rank(A^{t})$.

Comment: It is true that we haven't had the use of this property, which sometimes is very useful. Reasoning on columns looks sufficient in this case, maybe because "adding a column" makes "columns-acting" predominant.